# Spawn multiple processes with fork() and pass shared memory key as cmd arg

Tags: c, linux, shared-memory

I have a so-called `distributor` program which spawns another program `af_xdp_user` for each IP-address passed to `distributor`.
Before doing this, `distributor` generates a shared memory:

```
int create_shrd_memory(uint64_t size) {
    const int shmid = shmget(SHM_KEY, size, IPC_CREAT | IPC_EXCL);
    if(shmid == -1) {
        if(errno == EEXIST) {
            printf("Shared memory with Key %d already exists, continue...\n", SHM_KEY);
            return SHM_KEY;
        } else {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to obtain Shared Memory: %s\n", strerror(errno));
            perror("shmget");
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    return shmid;
}
```

This shared-memory-key is then passed to each sub-process as a command line argument (along several other arguments):

```
#define SHM_KEY 0x1235

bool global_exit = false;

static void exit_application(int signal)
{
    signal = signal;
    global_exit = true;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    const uint8_t amnt_of_ip_addrs = argc - 1;

    const int shmid = create_shrd_memory( sizeof(struct stats_record) * amnt_of_ip_addrs );

    char shrdmemid[96];
    char shrdmemidx[96];
    pid_t childs[amnt_of_ip_addrs];

    for(uint8_t ip_index = 1; ip_index < argc; ip_index++) {

        printf("Forked for IP: %s\n", argv[ip_index]);

        pid_t pid = fork();
        if(pid == 0) { /* child */

            static char argv_child[13][18] = { "af_xdp_user", "--dev", "eth20", "--shrdmem",  "", "--shrdmemidx", "", "--progsec", "xdp_sock", "--filename", "af_xdp_kern.o", "-Q", ""};

            sprintf(shrdmemid, "%d", shmid);
            sprintf(shrdmemidx, "%d", ip_index - 1);

            strcpy(argv_child[4], shrdmemid);
            strcpy(argv_child[6], shrdmemidx);
            strcpy(argv_child[12], shrdmemidx);

            printf("Arguments:\n");
            for(uint8_t arg_idx = 0; arg_idx < sizeof(argv_child) / sizeof(argv_child[0]); arg_idx++) {
                printf("\t%s\n", argv_child[arg_idx]);
            }

            execl("af_xdp_user", argv_child[0], argv_child[1], argv_child[2], argv_child[3], argv_child[4], argv_child[5], argv_child[6], argv_child[7], argv_child[8], argv_child[9], argv_child[10], NULL);

        } else if(pid < 0) {
            printf("FORK FAILED!\n");
        } else {
            // childs[ip_index - 1] = pid;
        }
    }

    signal(SIGINT, exit_application);

    while(!global_exit) {
        print_statistics(amnt_of_ip_addrs);
        sleep(2);
    }
}
```

With `print_statistics` being a function that accesses (in the future all `stats_record` structs) the first `stats_record`-struct of the shared memory and prints the amount of received packets:

```
void print_statistics(const int amnt_of_processes) {
    printf("STATISTICS:\n");
    char *shmd = shmat(SHM_KEY, NULL, 0);
    struct stats_record *stats = (struct stats_record*)(shmd);
    printf("\tREC PACKETS: %lu\n", stats->rx_packets);
}
```

Each subprocess with the program `af_xdp_user` then writes certain statistics about received IP-packets in a `struct stats_record` like this:

```
char *shm_data = shmat(cfg->shrdmem_id, NULL, 0);
if(shm_data == -1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to obain shared memory: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    exit(1);
}
struct stats_record *stats = (struct stats_record*)(shm_data + sizeof(struct stats_record) * cfg->shrdmem_idx);

...

stats->rx_bytes += amnt_of_packets * bytes;
stats->rx_packets += rcvd;

shmdt(shm_data);
```

I don't know if I got the idea of `fork()` right but I get this strange output:

```
$ sudo ./distributor 127.0.0.1
Shared memory with Key 4661 already exists, continue...
Forked for IP: 127.0.0.1
STATISTICS:
Arguments:
        af_xdp_user
        --dev
        eth20
        --shrdmem
        4661
        --shrdmemidx
        0
        --progsec
        xdp_sock
        --filename
        af_xdp_kern.o
        -Q
        0
SHRDMEM-ID: 4661
SHRDMEM-IDX: 0
Segmentation fault
$ RX-Queue: 0
...
Failed to obain shared memory: Invalid argument
```

Notice the second `$` I get on the command line. In my opinion, this means that `distributor` exited, but I don't know why it would exit?

Comment: The line `Segmentation fault` means that some process was killed because it tried to access an invalid memory address. I suggest to use a tool like `valgrind` to check for memory access errors.

Comment: what is `stats_record` ?

Comment: For the sake of a minimal reproducible example to help pare it down for people, can you rule out that it has anything to do with printing statistics, and if so remove that from the code example presented?

Comment: your shared memory are allocated with `const int shmid = create_shrd_memory( sizeof(struct stats_record) * amnt_of_ip_addrs );`  but used with `struct stats_record *stats = (struct stats_record*)(shm_data + sizeof(struct stats_record) * cfg->shrdmem_idx);`  you have an out of memory access

Comment: @Landstalker, and interesting the output shows SHRDMEM-IDX == 0

Comment: try : `gdb ./distributor` -> `run` -> `where` when segmentation fault  appears

Comment: @Landstalker Why is this a problem?

Comment: @binaryBigInt when you create the shared memory, you create it with a fix size `create_shrd_memory( sizeof(struct stats_record) * amnt_of_ip_addrs );`, But after you move your pointer with `shm_data + sizeof(struct stats_record) * cfg->shrdmem_idx)` you move it probably out of alocated area

Comment: No, I don't. Because `cfg->shrdmem_idx` is `0`, this means accessing the start of the shared memory. Furthermore, the problem is the line `shmat(...)` because it returns `-1`.

Comment: @binaryBigInt can you put a minimum code so that i can help you, because i can't compile your code

Comment: @binaryBigInt i d'ont know if you delete your shared memory somewhere with `shmctl (IPC_RMID )` because i have juste a part of your code

Answer (score 0):

I did some investigations on your program. Your segmentation fault is caused by this:

```
char *shmd = shmat(SHM_KEY, NULL, 0);
```

The `shmat` function must be used whith the generated **ID** and NOT the IPC **key** `SHM_KEY`.
Let's remember that the diagram is as follows :
1- Call shmget with `IPC_MEMORY_KEY` to get `IPC_MEMORY_ID`
2- Call shmat with the generated `IPC_MEMORY_ID`

In your case `char *shmd = shmat(SHM_KEY, NULL, 0);` you call `shmat` with a `Key` and not an `ID`. Therefore, your pointer is not valid.
In addition, i noticed that your program created abandoned shared memories:

```
ipcs -m
```

[image]

you must delete them in your code by calling :

```
shmctl(IPC_MEMORY_ID , IPC_RMID ,NULL); // ID and not Key !
```

Or, by commande line :

```
ipcrm -m MEM_ID (and not Key)
```

[image]